# Specify what implementation should be injected to class

Tags: c#

I have an interfaces : IBook and IMovie.
IBook is implemented by class Book, this class have object of IMovie.
IMovie is implemented by two classes : Movie1, Movie2

```cs
public class Book: IBook
{
   private IMovie _movie;
   public Book(IMovie movie) _movie = movie
}
```

In every case I want to inject Movie1 implementation to IBook, except one situation. In one class that have object of Book I want to inject Movie2 to Book. Is it possible to specify such a case ? Or maybe I shouldnt use DI in this case and create objects manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Ideas -

1 - You could have 2 interfaces/classes that inherit from IMovie/Movie of IMovie1 and IMovie2, register both and inject the relevant one.

2 - Create an IMovieFactory that has a method that takes some parameter to select the correct implementation and return the relevant implementation.

Comment: 2nd option is much better!

Comment: thanks for answear, I thought about Factory pattern but I wasnt sure. I will implement it in this way ;)